# Swift で TextField に取得してきた文字列を入れたい

Tags: swift

Swiftプログラミング初心者です。他のクラスから下記メソッドを呼び出して、TextFieldに取得してきた文字列を入れたいのですができていません。値を表示させるのにはどのようにすればいいのか、ご教授いただけないでしょうか？

**目標**
ストーリーボードのresultTextViewに、取得してきた文字列であるresultStringを表示したい。

**現在**
デバッグでresultStringに値が渡ってきていることはわかっていますが、resultTextViewのテキストフィールドに取ってきた値が反映されない。

**考察**
UITextField型のresultTextViewをString型に直せば良いのでしょうか？
そうであれば直しかたを教えていただきたいです。

```
@IBOutlet weak var resultTextView: UITextField!

func showResult(resultString: String) {
    resultTextView?.text = resultString
}
```

ご回答ありがとうございます。質問にお答えします。
①APIを叩いて得られたデータをJSON解析を行い帰ってきたデータを使っています。

```
Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseJSON { response in
                switch response.result {
                    // 処理成功時
                    case .success:
                            if let result = response.result.value as? [String: Any] {
                            //SwiftyJSONを使用してJSON解析
                                let json:JSON = JSON(response.data as Any)
                                var resultString = json["converted"].string
                                ResultVC.showResult(resultString: resultString!)
                            }
```

のようにResultViewControllerを呼び出しています。
②ストーリーボードへの接続は正しい接続となっております。

Comment: `showResult(resultString:)`をどこでどんなタイミングで呼び出しているのかによって、結果が変わってきます。また`resultTextView`がstoryboard上の`UITextField`と正しく接続されていますか?

Comment: ご質問分の編集ありがとうございます。ただ、追記されたコードでは`ResultVC`がどのようにインスタンス化されたのかがわかりません。`ResultVC`がどのように宣言されたのかと、そこにどのように`ResultViewController`のインスタンスを設定したのかがわかるコードをお示しいただけませんか?